# My credit card has no magnetic stripe. Is this a problem in the USA?

Tags: usa, money, payment-cards

My new credit card (Mastercard) has no magnetic stripe.  It has a chip, Near Field Communication (NFC), and the 16-digit number along with validity date and CVV code.  Will I encounter any limitations if I try to use it in the United States, for example to rent cars or hotel rooms?  In 2019, do magnetic stripe payments still exist in the USA or has chip and PIN (or chip and sign) meanwhile become ubiquitous there as well?  AFAIK the rest of the world uses chip and PIN (or no card payments at all), and if I remember correctly most payments I made in spring 2018 in the USA were with chip and PIN, but I'm not sure if magnetic stripe payments have disappeared like they did in Europe one or two decades ago.

This question differs from *[German credit card in the US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/117900/2509)* because my card doesn't have a magnetic strip at all.

Comment: You just need chip-and-whatever, not necessarily chip-and-pin specifically, right? I seem to recall that chip-and-signature is supposedly not uncommon in the US.

Comment: @HenningMakholm indeed, chip-and-PIN is almost unknown in the US.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Chip and sign works, I've even done that in Germany a couple of times.

Comment: Are you sure the card does not have a magnetic stripe? I've seen some cards that have different colored stripes other than black now, so if your card, say, silver, and so is the stripe, you might just not be able to see it.

Comment: @PhilippNagel Quite sure. There's certainly nothing visible in any color. I've read in various places that credit cards are delivered without magnetic stripes by default, only a minority of "world traveller" credit cards still have one.  Card issuers are liable for losses due to fraud and fraud is too easy with the magnetic strip, so they by default issue cards without. This has been the default in Germany for the past 5 years or so.

Comment: Wow, reading that cards have no magstripe by default is very interesting to read from over in Australia. My bank card (which allows credit operations, but is a debit card) has a stripe, chip contacts, and NFC. If I manage to swipe it on a terminal before NFC kicks in (have to be quick, lol), the screen tells me the card does not work with swiping and to insert it into the machine. (I can then either go "oh, right" and then tap it to use credit, or insert it to use credit/savings(EFTPOS)/cheque, all of which will prompt for my PIN.)

Answer (score 11):

At this point in 2019, nearly every credit card terminal in the US is set up to read both chip and contactless. There are still some exceptions out there, (e.g. you can't use contactless at Walmart because they want to force people to use their own payment app) but while they're uncommon it's hard to predict where you'll run into one. Except for paying at the pump at gas stations, which seems to be the last place where chips aren't read, but these probably wouldn't have worked with your card even if it had a magnetic stripe. (But in that case you just pay inside.) You'll probably want to have some cash on hand and/or another card, just to be sure.

P.S. While you didn't ask, someone else who reads this will need to know: If you use a MC/Visa Debit card at a US payment terminal, and it asks you "Debit or Credit", always select Credit. "Debit" in the US is a completely different network that MC/Visa do not run on.

Comment: According to [this infographic from Visa](https://usa.visa.com/visa-everywhere/blog/bdp/2019/05/28/chip-technology-helps-1559068467332.html), 75% of US storefronts accept chip cards.  It's a sizeable majority, but I'm not sure it should be described as "nearly every terminal".

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I wonder how they calculated that number? It certainly doesn't agree with my day to day experience. I live in a town of 23,000 in New Hampshire and I can't even think of any place that might not have a chip terminal. Wherever those other 25% are, they don't seem to be around here. Aside from Taco Bell (which finally activated their chip terminals this spring) and the aforementioned pay at the pump gas pumps, I haven't seen another retailer not accept chip transactions in years.

Comment: Upon further examination:  the fine print at the bottom says "[m]erchants that have completed an EMV transaction in the last 30 days are considered chip-activated."  My guess is that the remaining 25% are things like seasonal businesses with *no* transactions in the last 30 days, and/or stores with small clienteles/personnel who are set in their ways.  In all likelihood, far more than 75% of *transactions* take place at a storefront with chip card ability.

Comment: I run into quite a few stores in my area (town of around 75,000 people) that do have the chip terminals, but have signs taped over them indicating they are not activated. Tends to be mostly chain stores, I assume their IT processes for this conversion are just slow and cumbersome.

Comment: "but these probably wouldn't have worked with your card even if it had a magnetic stripe" -> not true for all cards, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11594/is-there-a-zip-code-i-can-enter-when-paying-at-the-pump-in-the-usa-with-a-foreig/22699

Comment: I've started to see chip & PIN even at pay-at-the-pump gas in the last couple of months in Indiana. Really threw me for a loop as I wasn't paying attention (habits die hard) and was wondering why it kept rejecting my card. Worked a treat once I read the screen and left the card in long enough to be processed.

Comment: Besides gas pumps, a lot of other self-service kiosk things don't yet accept chips either.  Parking meters, transit ticket machines, vending machines, etc.  And in these cases, there is often no attendant available to run the card manually.  Cash is usually still an alternative at these, but you may need exact change.  ATMs are another question, especially the generic ones in convenience stores etc, but hopefully OP is not going to need to use the card for cash advances anyway.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have a different debit card that I use to get cash and it has a magnetic stripe, although it still failed at some US kiosks after I was asked for my ZIP code (this was the Madison B-Cycle kiosk and whatever I tried for the ZIP code was denied)

Comment: Here in California, I still see a lot of restaurants using POS terminals with mag stripe readers on the side of the screen.

Comment: 1 in 4, or maybe even 1 in 3 restaurants still being magstripe only sounds about right for where I live (rural SW PA). There's one local fast food franchise that's magstripe or contactless but not chip, a combo I didn't even realize was valid until I saw it.

Comment: Most food trucks and other family businesses still require magstrips, as well as any card reader built into something large and heavy, like gas stations or mid-age vending machines.

Comment: It sounds like some of the comments here contradict the answer.  That would warrant another answer, contradicting the existing one.  Ideally, with multiple contradicting answers, would be evidence to pick it up (such as Michael Seifert has linked).  Perhaps there are branch-specific surveys as well?